# Why does gtk.Table takes twice as much space than it should?

Tags: python, gtk

I'm using *gtk.Table* in combination with an *EventBox* for every cell to draw a colored grid. After trying out a minimal example i've discovered that the window is twice as big as the actual table. Also it's not possible to shrink the window any further when the application is running.

[image]

It seems like something went horrible wrong but i'm not able to figure out the cause. Here's the minimal example to reproduce the misbehaviour:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

class MyProgram:

    def __init__(self):
        app_window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        app_window.set_border_width(10)
        app_window.connect("delete_event", lambda w,e: gtk.main_quit())
        vbox_app = gtk.VBox(False, 0)
        table_layout = gtk.Table(rows=1,columns=1, homogeneous=True)
        for col in range(1,10):
                for row in range(1,5):
                        event_box = gtk.EventBox()
                        label_day = gtk.Label("")
                        label_day.set_size_request(18,18)
                        label_day.show()
                        event_box.add(label_day)
                        event_box.modify_bg(gtk.STATE_NORMAL,
                                event_box.get_colormap().alloc_color("orange"))
                        event_box.set_border_width(25)
                        event_box.show()
                        table_layout.attach(event_box, 0, col, 0, row, 0,0,0,0)
        vbox_app.pack_start(table_layout)
        app_window.add(vbox_app)
        app_window.show_all()
        return

def main():
    gtk.main()
    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyProgram()
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out it's your `event_box.set_border_width(25)` that hurts. If you just want to space evenly your labels, us the padding arguments of `GtkTable::attach` instead.

Here are unrelated improvements:
don't connect `gtk_main_quit` to the `delete-event` signal, connect it to the `destroy` signal instead. `delete-event` is when you want to do something before quitting (for example, display a popup "are you sure ? yes/no"), but what you want is to quit gtk when the window is really destroyed.

Also, instead of prepending your widgets when adding them in the table, append them and use a range starting from 0 so it's easier to see where the widgets are added (the indexes in the table are zero-based).

As for your VBox, in this context it's useless. If you only have widget which content takes the whole window, just add it directly to your GtkWindow (but maybe it's needed in our unstripped version of the program).

Finally, you don't need to call `gtk_widget_show` on each widget. Just focus on constructing your widget hierarchy, and then run `gtk_widget_show_all` on the toplevel window. It will recursively show all the widgets in it.

That gives us in the end:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

class MyProgram:

    def __init__(self):
        app_window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        app_window.set_border_width(10)
        app_window.connect('destroy', lambda w: gtk.main_quit())
        table = gtk.Table(rows=1, columns=1, homogeneous=True)

        for col in range(0,9):
            for row in range(0,4):
                event_box = gtk.EventBox()
                label_day = gtk.Label('')
                label_day.set_size_request(18, 18)
                event_box.add(label_day)
                event_box.modify_bg(gtk.STATE_NORMAL,
                        event_box.get_colormap().alloc_color("orange"))
#                event_box.set_border_width(25)
                table.attach(event_box, col, col + 1, row, row + 1, 0, 0, 12, 12)
        app_window.add(table)
        app_window.show_all()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyProgram()
    gtk.main()
```

You also have a tool named [`gtk-inspector`](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK+/Inspector) but I don't know if it works with GTK 2. If not, fallback on `gtk-parasite`. These tools will help you analyze a running gtk user interface and see the characteristics of its widgets.

Also, GTK 3 has been out for a few years now and GTK 4 is on the road. Consider using GTK 3 for new code. It doesn't use pygtk anymore, it's pygobject instead trough the `gi` package (GObject introspection).

Here's the GTK 3 in python official tutorial:

https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: Thanks for your help and all the tips! Unfortunately for this project i'm forced to use GTK 2, but i'll definitely check out GTK 3 next time.